# Как установить Visual Studio в Docker-контейнер?

Tags: visual-studio, docker

Хочу установить Visual Studio в контейнер, чтобы работать на различных компьютерах с различными ОС. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Ахахах, как амбициозно) Вот только Вижак работает лишь на Винде, а внутри Докера крутятся Линуксы, в связи с чем мечте сей не суждено осуществиться ‍♀️ Не говоря уже о том, что в Докере крутятся процессы без GUI, и IDE там не заработает. А вот собрать виртуалку с нужным окружением и сохранить её образ для переиспользования вполне реально. Можно ещё на флэшку установить; или remote desktop себе сделать с сервера.

Comment: @AivanF., ну если хостом будет винда, то внутри докера тоже может быть винда. Впрочем, действительно без UI.

Comment: @AivanF. странно, а у меня билды собираются в докере в visual studio под виндой. пойду расскажу девопсам, что так нельзя :)

Comment: @AivanF спасибо